# ssh и фоновый запуск приложения

Tags: linux, bash, golang, ssh

Запускаю ssh коннект с выполнением команд (переход в папку, экспорт переменных для окружения go, вызов bash скрипта для убивания процесса go и компиляция программы с запуском в фоновом режиме. Выглядит это примерно так :

```
ssh login@myip -p myport 'cd /path/ && export GOROOT=/usr/local/go && export GOPATH=/path/ && export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin:$PATH && ./compile.sh'
```

далее сам скрипт compile.sh

```
pkill goserver
go build -o goserver main.go
./goserver &
```

в итоге происходит компиляция запуск программы но нет ухода в фон, а висит как будто запустил go run и при нажатии ctrl+c естественно умирает процесс.

А если зайти отдельно на сервер и запустить тот же compile.sh все отлично отрабатывает. в чем проблема ? подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: `screen`, `tmux`, `nohup` в конечном итоге...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

просто отправьте *stdout* процесса куда-нибудь: в «нормальный» файл или в `/dev/null`. варианты:

1. либо в самом скрипте:

   ```
   ./goserver >/dev/null &
   ```
2. либо при его вызове:

   ```
   $ ssh ... ' ... && ./compile.sh >/dev/null'
   ```

Comment: alexander barakin, большое спасибо, что-то не подумал про >/dev/null &, это как раз то что нужно :)

Answer (score 0):

Еще может помочь команда nohup, которая как раз задумана для решения таких задач.